# Android Studio и Gradle: настройки по умолчанию для нового проекта

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Как переписать начальные настройки Gradle для нового Android проекта?
Я установил новое Android API и удалил старые. Но при создании нового проекта `Gradle` выставляет `compileSdkVersion = 25` (удаленное). Ну и проект, разумеется, не компилируется, потому что этой API уже нет на компе.

Конечно, можно и руками самому менять, но хочется изменить это и еще парочку других значений по умолчанию.